# Get domain name from PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, com, active-directory

Assume that we have this context

```
private static readonly PrincipalContext Context = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "255.255.255.252",
                         "OU=TestOrgUnit,DC=as,DC=asf",
                         "blabla", "12345");
```

I'm searching for users in this domain. I get their's names as `SomeNickName`, but they should be `DomainName\SomeNickName`.

Is it possible to get a `DomainName` from `PrincipalContext` object? I found a solution for `DirectoryEntry`, but cannot convert `PrincipalContext` into it.

This code

```
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("255.255.255.252", "AdminLogin", "PWD");
```

and this code

```
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("255.255.255.252://OU=TestOrgUnit,DC=as,DC=asf", "AdminLogin", "PWD");
```

throws an exception and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So technically you have the domain info in the DN you've specified for the connecting OU (DC=as,DC=asf).  The first DC is the pre-Win2K name which seems to be what you're looking for.

As far as the PrincipalContext itself containing the domain info it seems that it doesn't.

If you want to use the DE to get more properties or to do your user search, you need to create it like this:

```
var deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://255.255.255.252/OU=TestOrgUnit,DC=as,DC=asf", "AdminLogin", "PWD")
```